# Fazer um projeto Netbeans que roda em pasta compartilhada VirtualBox não fazer upload

Tags: netbeans

Tenho uma VirtualBox rodando um servidor web Ubuntu/Apache/PHP. 
Configurei a pasta de aplicação no apache como /var/sf_www/
esta é uma pasta compartilhada com a minha máquina host.

Configurei Run Configuration no Netbeans como Remote Web Site, para acessar o ip da minha máquina virtual.

Sempre que rodo a aplicação no Netbeans ele executa o upload dos arquivos alterados para o servidor de aplicação, mas isso não é necessário, pois eu edito os arquivos na minha máquina local, que são compartilhados pela pasta de aplicação do meu servidor web.

Como fazer o Netbeans executar o servidor remoto sem fazer upload dos arquivos?

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isto, vá nas configurações de sua maquina virtual e crie uma pasta compartilhada.

```
Settings dialog > Shared Folders
```

Neste exemplo nomeie a pasta compartilhada como "Server". Na opções deixe marcado apenas "Tornar permanente".

Agora rode a maquina virtual e instale os programas adicionais do virtualbox no linux

```
Devices > CD/DVD Devices > VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
```

Monte o CD com o comando

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom
```

execute o comando abaixo para baixar alguns pacotes necessários para a instalação das ferramentas do virtualbox

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname –r`
```

Logo em seguida vamos para a instalação das ferramentas

```
Para 32bit: sudo /cdrom/VBoxLinuxAddition-x86.run
Para 64bit: sudo /cdrom/VBoxLinuxAddition-amd64.run
```

Reinicie a maquina

```
sudo reboot
```

Para que o não tenha trabalho para mudar ou criar virtualhosts no apache, monte sua pasta compartilhada em /var/www

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=33,gid=33 Server /var/www;
```

Preste atenção para a parte `uid=33,gid=33` isso representa o código do usuário e o grupo em que o apache roda. Normalmente `www-data`. Altere caso o apache esteja configurado para usar outro usuário, pois caso contrário terá problemas com permissão ao rodar seus scripts.

Para que não precise montar sua pasta compartilhada toda vez que iniciar a maquina virtual, adicione um script de inicialização.

```
cd /etc/init.d/
sudo vi sharedfolder.sh
```

cole o código abaixo no arquivo e salve apertando `ESC` > `:wq` > `ENTER`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=33,gid=33 Server /var/www;
```

Agora você pode permitir que o Netbeans rode seus projetos diretamente de uma pasta local. Assim ele não irá fazer upload do projeto.

Para configurar o XDebug na maquina virtual e possibilitar o Netbeans executar normalmente o debug altere as configurações do XDebug no `php.ini` da seguinte maneira

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host={IP da maquina virtual}
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

Pronto, ambiente configurado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar o upload para manual nas propriedades do projeto, conforme o link (em inglês)
https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/remote_synchronization

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Por isso, e porque é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui mesmo, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta? Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)